# Why do I get a compile error when calling start method?

Tags: java

My program -

```
class RunnableA implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Program A");
    }
}
class MyThread extends Thread{

}
class Demo{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        RunnableA a1=new RunnableA();
        a1.start(); 

    }
}
```

And I got this when compiling.

> Demo.java:12: error: cannot find symbol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`start` is a method of `Thread` class, not a method of the Runnable interface.

Here's a way to start a `Thread` that would run your Runnable's logic :

```
class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        RunnableA a1=new RunnableA();
        new Thread(a1).start(); 
    }
}
```